# How to access JSON object indexes by a string generated inside a iteration

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
value = {
"montoBase01": 10,
"montoBase02": 5,
"montoBase03": 34,
"montoBase04": 5,
"montoBase05": 25,
"montoBase06": 134,
"montoBase07": 25,
"montoBase08": 345,
"montoBase09": 23,
"montoBase10": 45,
"montoBase11": 234,
"montoBase12": 5
};
```

And I want to retrieve each index using a loop function like a for e.g.

```
for(i=1;i<=12;i++){
   var index = ""; 
   if(i<10)
      index = "montoBase0"+i;
   else
      index = "montoBase"+i;
   var mb = value.index
}
```

But I'm always getting undefined values, is it possible to retrieve the indexes dynamically? if it is, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you actually want, provided Json has  no relation to `for ` statement

Comment: some other options to iterate the indexes? Because I'm just iterating the index name, not the object itself

Comment: I want to retrieve each index name from an iteration and then access to the object index.

Comment: Are you trying to get properties where value is less than or equal to 12? Or iterate entire object? Not sure what expected result is?

Comment: I just changed the name to avoid more misunderstandings, sorry about that again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to iterate properties and values of an object

```js
let value = {
  "montoBase01": 10,
  "montoBase02": 5,
  "montoBase03": 34,
  "montoBase04": 5,
  "montoBase05": 25,
  "montoBase06": 134,
  "montoBase07": 25,
  "montoBase08": 345,
  "montoBase09": 23,
  "montoBase10": 45,
  "montoBase11": 234,
  "montoBase12": 5
};

for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(value)) {
  // do stuff with `key`, `val`
  console.log(key, val);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting solution, I'm kinda new in jQuery. I will try to learn some tricks like this. Thank you

Comment: @ManuelVasquezPimentel This is actually much better solution, use it instead.

Comment: @ManuelVasquezPimentel The Answer has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: oh ok, well I'm new at javascript too

Comment: @Kinduser u're right, the whole point is get what I need and also reduce the amount of code.

Comment: @ManuelVasquezPimentel It's pure javascript, enjoy it's simplicity. (My pleasure, Mr Guest (: )

Answer (score 0):

You must use square brackets

```
$.formatField(value["montoBase0"+i])
$.formatField(value["montoBase"+i])
```

or:

```
 index = "montoBase0"+i;
 var mb = value[index]
```

Read [Property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Just a note: the `value` var is an object, not a JSON :)

Comment: Yes, I didn't expressed the question title properly, sorry about that :(

Answer (score 0):

Try built in function of jQuery `.each()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

value = {
"montoBase01": 10,
"montoBase02": 5,
"montoBase03": 34,
"montoBase04": 5,
"montoBase05": 25,
"montoBase06": 134,
"montoBase07": 25,
"montoBase08": 345,
"montoBase09": 23,
"montoBase10": 45,
"montoBase11": 234,
"montoBase12": 5
};

$.each(value, function(key, value){
if(value < 10)
  console.log("montoBase0"+value);
else
  console.log("montoBase"+value)
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```